# Delete a row from MySQL by passing the ID via javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to delete a row from a table in MySql by passing the id via javascript function like that :

```js
function delete_slider(id){
  <?php 
      $delete = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM slider where id ="?> id <?php echo "LIMIT 1);";
      $delete->execute();
  ?>
}
```

```html
onclick="delete_slider(<?php echo $slider->id ?>);"
```

Comment: it doesn't work that way, you will need to call your php function via AJAX

Comment: It seems you have just started. You are trying to mix javascript and php. One is client side and another is server side. You need to do some study for this. As @cmorrissey explained AJAX may an option, but still you need to figure it out.

Comment: This `$delete = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM slider where id ="?> id <?php echo "LIMIT 1);";` is invalid PHP/SQL. The `id` needs to be sent to this PHP script via ajax and the value should be passed into the execute or as bound.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an AJAX call indeed.
First you need to make a route or an URL that activates your function.
As second you need to use this as a JQuery AJAX call

```
var domain = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2] + "/";



$("myButtonId").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        method: "DELETE", // or if you didn't enable a delete call you can use a GET or POST call but it isn't nice
        url: domain + "thisIsMyLinkToDelte/deletePage/" + ID
    })  
});
```

and then your application should work fine.

If you want to learn how it works you can do it at this webpage http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have Syntax errors in your `SQL`, you better use `AJAX` :

**AJAX**

```
function delete_slider(id){
    $.post("your_script.php",
    {
        slider_id: id
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
$delete = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM slider where id = ? LIMIT 1;");
$delete->execute(array($_POST['slider_id']));
if($delete->rowCount() > 0){
    echo 'deleted';
}else{
    echo 'no affected rows';
}
```